# How to add an icon to an iOS static uitableview cell in the storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I've created a UITableView with three static cells. This is serving as a submenu for a "More..." section. I would like to have an icon for each of the three cells but there does not seem to be any way to control the size and position of the label in the content view so as to move it over to the right and thus leave room for the icon on the left. The label does not seem to move nor can it be resized.

Is there any way to do this in the storyboard? If absolutely necessary, I could do this in code, but I'd prefer to just accomplish this in the storyboard if possible.

Here's a screenshot of what I want.[image]

Comment: draag and drop label and use it

Comment: Set the cell as Custom in Storyboard?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just go to your cell's Attributes inspector, set cell style to Basic. Add your desired image to image section.

[image: Example Image]

Comment: wah mere sher:)

Comment: how can I resize the icon after this?